# Appending numbers from list as values of a dictionary without if condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to append the elements in a list `ids` to a `dictionary_la`.
So my `dictionary_la` is generated as,

```
col1         = [x.split('_')[5] for x in l1]
col1

['MOB',
 'MOB',
 'MOB',
 'MOB',
 'ASP',
 'ASP',
 'ASP',
 'ASP',
 'YIP',
 'YIP',
 'YIP',
 'YIP']

dictionary_la = dict((y,[]) for y in col1)
dictionary_la
{'MOB': [], 'ASP': [], 'YIP': []}

ids= ["1","2"]
```

Now I wanna append the elements in list `ids` to my dictionary `dictionary_la`. Without any `, if the condition`
In the end, I need the dictionary as following,

```
{'MOB': [1,2], 'ASP': [1,2], 'YIP': [1,2]}
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: `dictionary_la = { y : [1,2] for y in col1}`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you need an `if`? Isn't `dictionary_la["MOB"].extend(ids)` good enough? Can you provide the code where you _do_ use an `if`?

Comment: I have never tried `extend()` thanks for the suggestion. Well, you use` if ` if you wanna make sure the value string has part of the key. However, that is in case of strings

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the value string has part of the key". Why do you need to compare the key and the value, if you're going to set the same value for every key no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Initiating the `ids` before itself and appending it with the dictionary.

```
l1 = ["JAF", "JAF", "JAF", "JAF", "SYD", "SYD"]
ids = [1,2]
dictionary_la = {y: ids for y in l1}
print(dictionary_la)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'JAF': [1, 2], 'SYD': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You can keep expanding the dictionaries and the list and it'll sure work.

```
a = {'MOB':[],'ASP':[],'YIP':[]}
b = ['1','2']

for i in a:
    for j in range(len(b)):
        a[i].append(b[j])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'MOB': ['1', '2'], 'ASP': ['1', '2'], 'YIP': ['1', '2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is :

```
dictionary_la = {'MOB': [], 'ASP': [], 'YIP': []}
ids = [1,2]

print(dictionary_la)

dictionary_la['MOB'] = ids
dictionary_la['ASP'] = ids
dictionary_la['YIP'] = ids
print(dictionary_la)
```

Output:

> {'MOB': [1, 2], 'ASP': [1, 2], 'YIP': [1, 2]}